# How to get page body after POST request

Tags: php, request, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a PHP page that lets you upload a document to telegram servers and than retrives a file_id which is stored in the json of the redirect page. After some tutorials on YT this is the code:

```
<?php
    $botToken = "1099xxxxxx:AxxxE-g9qDI2Uxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
?>

<form action="<?php echo $website.'/sendPhoto' ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="chat_id" value="mychatid">
    <input type="file" name="photo">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

[Redirect after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBQ3B.png)

The goal is to retrive the file_id of the file and save it in a variable, possibly without opening another tab.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `file_id`? Your screenshot has at least 2.

Answer (score 1):

You've making the request to the Telegram API **from the browser** by submitting a form directly to it.

There is no way your PHP can get any information from that API that way.

As a side effect, you are giving your token (which should be kept secret) to every visitor who uses the form.

You need the browser to submit the form to *a PHP program you control* and then make the request to the Telegram API *from your PHP* and not from the browser.

The usual way to do this is with the [cURL library](https://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: Thanks, I can now retrive a json like format with `$result = curl_exec($curl);` but I want to access the file_id proprety. I tried decoding with `$decoded = json_decode($result, true);` but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?